# Secure file download

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to develop a secure file download in aspnetboilerplate template with .net core web api and angular 2.0

i tried this on in  Web.host but it is not treating as API

```
public class DownloadController : ProjectControllerBase
    {
        private IHostingEnvironment _env;
        public FileResult DownloadYourFile()
        {
            try
            {
                long uid = (AbpSession.UserId == null) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt64(AbpSession.UserId);
                var net = new System.Net.WebClient();
                string path = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "downloads/xyz.doc");                                     
                var data = net.DownloadData(path);
                var content = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
                var contentType = "APPLICATION/octet-stream";
                var fileName = "xyz.doc";
                return File(content, contentType, fileName);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new UserFriendlyException("Error", "Error downloading file. Please try again.", e);
            }            
        }

    }
```

how can i do this in Web.Application layer

Comment: What do you mean by `not treating as API`?

Comment: @aaron it is not displaying in swagger. how can i write it in web.application any idea

Comment: Is it sufficient if it appears in Swagger? It's not trivial nor recommended to do this in Application layer — and there's no practical benefit in doing that.

Comment: @aaron no it is not coming in api

Answer (score 1):

Packages to be installed from Nuget

```
1. Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles // To Get MimeType
2. NSwag.Annotations // Map API Return Type to NSwag Generate Method Return Type
```

**Then In ConfigureServices Method In Startup.cs**,

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    // Swagger Configurations
    options.MapType<FileContentResult>(() => new Schema
    {
        Type = "file"
    });
});
```

**Add a method to get the MimeType of the file in a service**

```
private string GetMimeType(string fileName)
{
    var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
    string contentType;
    if (!provider.TryGetContentType(fileName, out contentType))
    {
        contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    }
    return contentType;
}
```

**Get the Required File in service creating a method**

```
public FileContentResult GetFile(string filename)
{
   // _environment is instance of IHostingEnvironment
    var filepath = Path.Combine($"{this._environment.WebRootPath}\\PATH-TO-FILE\\{filename}");

    // Get the MimeType of file
    var mimeType = this.GetMimeType(filename);
    byte[] fileBytes;
    if (File.Exists(filepath))
    {
        fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath); 
    } 
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("File Not Found");
    }

    return new FileContentResult(fileBytes, mimeType)
    {
        FileDownloadName = filename
    };
}
```

**Add a method to return file from service**

```
[SwaggerResponse(200, typeof(FileContentResult))]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(FileContentResult), 200)]
public FileContentResult DownloadDocument(string fileName)
{
    // Call the method in Step 3
    return this._service.GetFile(fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To display your new method in Swagger, you can do this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")] //Should add route config for your controller
public class TestController : AbpCoreControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet] //Should add HttpMethod to your method
    public string TestMethod()
    {
       return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

To secure file download, I think you can do:

- Add AbpAuthorize attribute to your controller/method
- Inject PermissionChecker if you need to check permission manually

Get more detail [here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Authorization)

Answer (score 0):

@tiennguyen answer's is correct.

Swagger doesn't show unconventional method names. So you have to write [Route] attribute. To be listed in Swagger is not crutial. You are able call the action.

```
 [AbpMvcAuthorize]
 [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
 public class  DownloadController : ProjectControllerBase
 {          
    public FileResult DownloadYourFile()
    {
            ....       
    }    
 }
```